# ELM update two fields in model

Tags: functional-programming, elm

How can i update two fields in model at once?
Now i have request that return me an alias with {price: Float, productId: Int}
I need to update two fields in model like model.price and model.productId

I looking for something like that, but its not work (ofc)

```
    case maybeProduct of
        Just product ->
       ( { model | price = product.price && 
           model | productId = product.productId}
            , Cmd.none
            )
        Nothing ->
            ( model
               , Cmd.none
             )
```

I found some info where advice that I can create two functions 
(Model -> Product -> Model) and do something like:

```
setPrice : Model -> Product -> Model
setPrice model product =
    { model | price = product.price }

setProductId : Model -> Product -> Model
setProductId model product =
    { model | companyId = product.productId }

                Just product ->
                        let
                            newModel =
                                product
                                    |> setPrice model
                                    |> setProductId model
                        in
                        ( newModel
                        , Cmd.none
                        )
                    Nothing ->
                        ( model
                           , Cmd.none
                         )
```

but something dont work. It looks like product dont passing in each function

i recieve

> The argument is:
>
> ```
> Model
> ```
>
> But (|>) is piping it a function that expects:
>
> ```
> { companyId : Int, price : Float }
> ```

Where i mistake? Or maybe there is different way to update two fields in model?

Comment: You should have a look at the Elm documentation, this is one of the first things they cover in the tutorials: https://elm-lang.org/docs/records#updating-records

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### How to update two fields at once:

Do something like this (this excludes commands by the way - you can add that in to suit your requirements):

```
{ model | price = new_price, productId = newProductId}
```

If you want to add Commands then you can do this:

```
({ model | price = new_price, productId = newProductId}, nameOfYourCommand)
```

### Documentation:

Here is a link that @JackLeow very kindly posted: https://elm-lang.org/docs/records#updating-records